# How to print arraylist data into separate lines in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, arraylist, console-application

**Why doesn't the console window print the array contents vertically rather than horizontally?
Is there a way to change that?**
How can I display the content of my array horizontally instead of vertically, with a Console.WriteLine()?

C#

```
        ArrayList tryArray = new ArrayList();
            for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
            {
              // ASKING FOR THE USER TO ENTER DETAILS
              Console.WriteLine("Please enter information for customer: " + i);
              Console.WriteLine("Please enter your customer name");
              cusName = Console.ReadLine();
              tryArray.Add(cusName); 

              Console.WriteLine("Please enter your customer id");
              cusID = Console.ReadLine();
              tryArray.Add(cusID);

              Console.WriteLine("No of months for membership ? (Range 1-120)");
              memMonths = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
              tryArray.Add(memMonths.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,10} {2,10}}", "Customer Name","Customer ID", "Months");

            for (int j = 0; j < tryArray.Count; j++)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,5} {2,5}", tryArray[j], tryArray[j], tryArray[j]);
            }


    **//code print like this right now
    Customer Name Customer ID Months
    a1            a1          a1
    a1234567      a1234567    a1234567
    12            12          12
    a2            a2          a2
    a2234567      a2234567    a2234567
    15            15          15

    //Result I want
    Customer Name Customer ID Months
    a1            a1234567    12 
    a2            a2234567    15**
```

Comment: You're using the same index 'tryArray[j]' for all your values on a line. So if that value is 'a1', you've got it showing 3 times. Can you show a structure of the data?

Comment: `for (int j = 0; j < tryArray.Count - 2; j++) { Console.WriteLine("{0,-10} {1,5} {2,5}", tryArray[j], tryArray[j + 1], tryArray[j + 2]); }`

Comment: The orgnization of the data can be improved. You now have an array like `{ name1, cusid1, memMonths1, name2, cusid2, memMonths2, . . . }`. Have a struct or a class containing  Name, CusID and MemMonths for example, to structurize the storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use a list and a class like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

            customers.Add(new Customer("a1", "a1234567", 12));
            customers.Add(new Customer("a2", "a2234567", 15));

            foreach (Customer c in customers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(c.Name +" "+ c.Id+" "+ c.Months);
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        class Customer
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public int Months { get; set; }

            public Customer(string name, string id, int months)
            {
                Name = name;
                Id = id;
                Months = months;
            }
        }
```

Output:

```
a1 a1234567 12
a2 a2234567 15
```